# Merge two bootstrap columns to one and keep order

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a layout where i want to keep images in two columns. Because images can be different height the columns should be independend of eachother. When viewed in an low resolution device i want the images to be in one column. At the moment i have solved it like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="">
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x50" alt="">
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x50" alt="">
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="">
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/LLd65ehe/

The problem is that i also want to add images dynamically to these colums. For example there is an "load more images" button and it loads 10 more images. At the moment i have an ajax script that loads these images and adds them to the column that has less height one by one. This works well if i have two columns side by side so the latest images will always be at the bottom. The problem with this solution is that when the columns are under eachother then depending on height latest images can be loaded somewhere in the middle.

How can this be solved? Or maybe the whole approach is wrong an there is a better way to acchive what im trying to do?

Comment: Just a quick comment - you don't need to have all media queries `col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12` on your column element. Bootstrap works in a "mobile first" approach, so you can set the media to `col-xs-12 col-sm-6` and that will set all larger queries to use the 50% width.

Comment: What do you mean by 'depending on height latest images can be loaded somewhere in the middle' ? The image would be loaded in either of these columns, right? Not sure what 'in the middle ' implies here.
Perhaps if you could explain with some illustation, then we can try to help

Comment: So with non mobile view these two columns are side by side. If i add an image at the end of either column the image appears in the bottom and thats all good. Now when i view the page in mobile then these two columns will be under eachother. This means that if i add an image to column 1 then it will not be the most bottom image - it will be the most bottom image of column1 but then there are all the images of column2 underneith so it will be kind of in the middle of all the images.

Comment: @user1985273 Okay. Have added an answer. Check if it fits the bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am leaving my previous answer as it is because it might be useful to someone.
If others feel the previous answer is not helpful, let me know and I will delete it.

The new answer is this one.

There is an interesting property in bootstrap grid that first columns for every row, if not cleared floats (clear:both), tend to move towards the side which has lesser height.
i.e.
if a row has 2 columns, and a third column is added, it will be the first column of the second row. Same holds for 5th, 7th and every odd column
Now:
1. If the first column is shorter than the 2nd one, then the 3rd column will automatically move to left
2. OTOH, if 2nd column is shorter than first column, then the 3rd column will automatically move to right.

This automatically takes care of your requirement, that the new element be added to the shorter side.

Also, since elements are being added in natural order (no moving around using JavaScript), they also automatically stackup vertically in the correct order (i.e. chronologically) and with the latest element being at the bottom.

So far, evrything is good.
Now comes the tricky part.

Remember, the condition 1 i.e when the 1st column is shorter than 2nd column?
Yes, that one.
Well in this case the column does move to the correct side **BUT** it does not appear in a masonry style. It appears in the grid style (which OP wants to avoid) i.e looking like it and the subsequent columns are separate from the previous columns.
Interestingly this does not happen in condition 2.

To fix this for condition 1, we need to add `float:right` to the previous column.

So without any further ado, here are the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shariqkhan/ft6n5a44/6/) and the codesnippet for the same.

Note that in the resize function, I have hardcoded the width to 1004 to check whether the screen is large or small. You might want to use better method for detection, keeping in mind the breakpoints as per the bootstrap grid.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var numColumns = 2;

jQuery(window).resize(function() { 
 //if(window.width >= 992) {
 if(jQuery('.thumbnail-container').width() >= 1005) {
  for(i = 2; i <= numColumns; i++) {
   currElement = jQuery('.thumbnail-container .columns:eq(' + (i-1) + ')'); //index starts at 0
   prevElement = jQuery('.thumbnail-container .columns:eq(' + (i-2) + ')'); //index starts at 0
   
   parentElem = jQuery('.thumbnail-container');
   parentElemLeft = prevElement[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
   parentElemRight = prevElement[0].getBoundingClientRect().right; 
   
   currElemBottom = currElement[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
   currElemLeft = currElement[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
   prevElemBottom = prevElement[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

   if((currElemLeft > ((parentElemRight-parentElemLeft)/2) ) && currElemBottom > prevElemBottom) {
    jQuery(currElement).addClass('so-pull-right');
   }
  }
 }
});


jQuery('#load-btn').click(function(e){
 console.log('clickeddddd');

 randomNum = getRandomInt(20,200);
 var imgSize = '100x' + randomNum;
 
 currElement = jQuery('.thumbnail-container .columns:eq(' + (numColumns-1) + ')'); //index starts at 0
 prevElement = jQuery('.thumbnail-container .columns:eq(' + (numColumns-2) + ')'); //index starts at 0
 
 parentElem = jQuery('.thumbnail-container');
 parentElemLeft = prevElement[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
 parentElemRight = prevElement[0].getBoundingClientRect().right;
    
 currElemBottom = currElement[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
 currElemLeft = currElement[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
 prevElemBottom = prevElement[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

 if((currElemLeft > ((parentElemRight-parentElemLeft)/2) ) && currElemBottom > prevElemBottom) {
  jQuery(currElement).addClass('so-pull-right');
 }
 
 numColumns++;
 
 elemToAdd = '<div class="col-md-6 columns"><p class="text-center"> COLUMN ' + numColumns +'</p>';
 elemToAdd += '<a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/' + imgSize + '" alt=""></a>';
 elemToAdd += '</div>';
  
 jQuery('.thumbnail-container').append(elemToAdd);
 
 e.preventDefault();
 return false;
});
```

```css
 
.button-container {
 padding: 10px 0;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
 .so-pull-right {
  float: right !important;
 }
}
.COLUMN_1 img {
 border:1px solid blue;
}
.COLUMN_2 img {
 border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row button-container">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
   <button id="load-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Load More</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row thumbnail-container">
  <div class="col-md-6 columns ">
   <p class="text-center"> COLUMN 1 </p>
   <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x50" alt="">
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 columns">
   <p class="text-center"> COLUMN 2 </p>
   <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="">
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for the height of the column element, and then decide where to append the new image, you could calculate the total height of all the elements in each column, and then decide where to add the new image.

```
function addImage(image) {
    var col1 = $('selectable-querystring'),
        col2 = $('selectable-querystring'),
        col1height = 0,
        col2height = 0;
    $.each(col1.find('img'), function(key, value) {
        col1height += value.height;
    });
    $.each(col2.find('img'), function(key, value) {
        col2height += value.height;
    });
    if (col1height >= col2height) {
       /* append image to col1 */
    }
    else {
       /* append image to col2 */
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand how this is any different from just looking at the whole column height? Wont i still have the problem that when the two columns are under eachother then new images will be loaded to the end of the top column and so for the users point of view in the middle of other images?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Editing the answer after getting a better understanding of the question.

Your requirement is that the column that the latest thumbnail gets added to should be displayed later when vertically stacked. This is possible only it is AFTER the other column in the HTML markup (unless you come up with absolute positioning hacks)
For this you have to keep swapping the columns' positions depending on which column has the latest thumbnail been added to.
Additionally, you will need to assign pull-left and pull-right classes to column 1 and column 2 respectively, so that while horizontally aligned they still appear in the original order i.e first Column 1 and then Column 2

I have added a Code snippet for this. Here is the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shariqkhan/ft6n5a44/1/) for the same.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}



jQuery('#load-btn').click(function(e){
 randomNum = getRandomInt(1,100);
 var imgSize = '100x50';
 
 if(randomNum%2 == 0) {
  imgSize = '100x150';
 }
 
 elemToAdd = '<a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/' + imgSize + '" alt=""></a>';
 
 //Now find out the shorter column 
 height_1 = jQuery('.COLUMN_1').height();
 height_2 = jQuery('.COLUMN_2').height();
 
 columnToAddTo = '.COLUMN_1';
 
 if(height_2 < height_1) {
  columnToAddTo = '.COLUMN_2';
 }
 
 jQuery(columnToAddTo).append(elemToAdd);
 
 /*Now the columns have to moved around, so that the column to which 
 the thumbnail was added is at the bottom. This means it has to be 
 AFTER the other columnn in the markup */
 
 jQuery('.thumbnail-container').append(jQuery(columnToAddTo));
 
 
 e.preventDefault();
 return false;
});
```

```css
.button-container {
 padding: 10px 0;
}
.COLUMN_1 img {
  border:1px solid blue;
}
.COLUMN_2 img {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row button-container">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
   <button id="load-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Load More</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row thumbnail-container">
  <div class="COLUMN_1 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-left">
   <p class="text-center"> COLUMN ONE </p>
   <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x50" alt="">
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="COLUMN_2 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-right">
   <p class="text-center"> COLUMN TWO </p>
   <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="">
   </a>
   <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="">
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Tried it in jsfiddle but this results in images being in a grid, the exact thing im trying to avoid:

https://jsfiddle.net/LLd65ehe/2/

Comment: Not quite what im looking for. The order still keeps shifting and images are not in a chronological order. For example if column one has items 1 and 2 and column two has items 3 and 4 and then a item 5 is loaded into column one then the order will be 3, 4, 1, 2, 5. Also on the button press i will be loading multiple images so dividing them really wont work.

Comment: "then the order will be 3, 4, 1, 2, 5"
Is this not what you want and also what is happening.

Regarding multiple images being added, I believe you can handle that too if the case for a single image is tackled.

Comment: Nope, i want the order to be always chronological - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: Its is not coming in chronological order because you are not adding elements consecutively. i.e in the example you gave element 5 is added after element 2 and not 5. So chronological order goes berserk.

However, with a bit tweaking we can still fix that.
Hang on for a while..working on the fix

Comment: Added a new answer (the old answer is as it is). Check that one now.